# Android Studio drawable xxhdpi-v4

Tags: java, android, xml, size, drawable

The size of my app is larger than I expected, all my drawble are 95% .SVG and are converted to XML in Android studio. When I did APK analyzer it shows xxhdpi-v4 take up most of the size and inside is .PNG generated. How do prevent android studio from generating this drawables directories.

**APK analyser :**

[image]

Comment: What is your `minSdkVersion`?

Comment: The minSdkVersion is 18.

Comment: See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources#vector-drawables-backward-solution and try following those instructions for updating your Gradle settings. Vector drawables only work natively on Android 5.0 (API Level 21) and higher. If you want to support older devices than that, either Android Studio will generate PNGs for you (which you do not like), or you will need to switch to the alternative backwards-compatible solution covered in that documentation.

Comment: you can use proguard rules to reduce app size.

Comment: I got it right.